How to download plotly graphs with the hover data points in R?
I have a plotly graph in R where I want to download the graph as a .png with the "compare data on hover" at a specific x value. Since I need to do it for a lot of graphs, moving the mouse pointer to a specific location and taking  a screenshot becomes tedious and unreliable as I want the same plot area.

It can be done, but you have to define the curvenumber and pointnumber plotly assigns to query a hover event. Since it varies significantly between plot types (since it goes from R => JS)  I can point you in a direction, but not offer much more assistance with a reproducible problem. Here's how to do it Javascript.
